# NodeJS pkg how to specify main function

Tags: node.js

Basically I was doing some testing with the npm package named `pkg` [This one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg)

I was able to compile successfully and the program was running great if i were to run it through command prompt, but when i would just try double clicking the executable, i would get a command prompt window open for a split seconds and then close again, this is the code i tried testing it with

```
let prompt = require("prompt-sync")
async function run() {
    let result = await a()
    console.log(result)
    let b = await prompt.query("input test ")
    console.log(b)
}
run();
```

This all worked just fine when i ran the compiled app through command prompt, but doesnt work when i double click the app

What I've tried so far:

1. Tried different function names which may be used (such as main(), run(), etc.)
2. Tried different node targets
3. Tried looking at the v8 flags (though there was a lot so I might have missed some)

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after a bit of testing i found i can do the following:

1. Make a while loop with while true and then to prevent many many many instances of the program opening because of the while true statement, i just define a variable outside the while true and then i put an if statement checking if the value is changed or not and if not it will run the run function otherwise it will just skip over.

```js
let i = 0;
function run() {
    console.log("hi")
}
while (true) {
    if(i === 0) {
        run();
        i++;
    }
}
```

Like this it will just run the program once while still not just popping up for a split second and closing.

This is not exactly what I wanted but this works the same way, which is good enough.